# Redirect tty out to serial?

Tags: remote, console, ilo, serial

Im trying to debug an issue we are having with netbooting a RedHat box. The anaconda installer scribbles useful log data to the second virtual terminal (Ctrl-Alt-F2) but I would like to be able to see this without being there (Box is racked and difficult to access). How can I edit the inittab to redirect the output so it *streams* to the serial port provided by the HP iLO card ? - I am familiar with setting up serial consoles for login, but not for redirecting like this?

Comment: what is your debugging target? boot loader or kernel? if you already have iLO, you can see all console output from remote console.  what is your point?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something similar to that ?

http://linux.koolsolutions.com/2009/03/29/howto-redirecting-linux-console-output-over-serial-port-on-another-machine/

The general idea is to define in boot-time where the output will be directed.
For example ...

```
kernel          /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.26-1-686 root=/dev/hda1 ro vga=791 quiet console=tty0 console=ttyS0,38400n8
```